# pandas ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (0,) (198,)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parameters

I am trying to capture a nested list of dicts in a dataframe. This is my code

```
           meta=['column1', 'column2','column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7', 
           'column8']
         df = pd.json_normalize(json_result[0][0:198], record_path= 
           ['column9'], meta = meta[0:10][0:198] )
```

column7 and column 8 have empty lists. If I remove the column7 and column8 from meta, everything is fine. Only when I include these two columns I get the error. It's probably because of the empty lists. How to solve this error?

Comment: what version of pandas do you use?

Comment: 1.2.4- pandas version

Answer (score 0):

your issue could be related to [this issue with pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37782#issuecomment-1146338699), looks like you may have to wait for the issue to be fixed in a new release.

until then, it sounds like the solution would be to remove your empty columns from the meta.  not the ideal workaround, but hopefully pandas fixes that bug soon.

(this is more of a comment than an answer, but i apparently need more reputation to be allowed to comment...)